# Missing value imputation with nearest neighbour

Tags: machine-learning, missing-data, data-imputation

I'm using k-nearest neighbour imputation method for missing values. This method has two tuning parameters: k and the distance metric. I see two options for applying this imputation method:

1. Inside nested cross-validation. Applying the imputation method separately to the training and testing set. If I'm using leave-one-out cross-validation this will not work because my test set only contains one data point.
2. Outside cross-validation by just imputing over the whole dataset.

Which is the right way to go?

Answer (score 1):

You should fit your imputer on the **training set** only. This way the imputation on the **test set** will be based only on the knowledge of the **training set**. If you impute missing data on the **whole dataset**, you will loose training/test set separation as some information from the test set would **leak** to training.